# Perl : implementing socket programming ( system() never returns)

Tags: perl, sockets, fork, system, openssh

My aim : implement socket programming such that client tries connecting to server if server not installed on remote machine , client(host) on its part transfers a tar file to server(target) machine and a perl script. This perl script untar the folder and runs a script (server perl script) , now the problem is : this server script has to run forever ( multiple clients ) until the machine restarts or something untoward happens.
so the script runs properly : but since it is continuously running the control doesnt go back to the client which will again try to connect to the server ( on some predefined socket) , so basically i want that somehow i run the server but bring back control to my host which is client in this case.

here is the code :

```
my $sourcedir = "$homedir/host_client/test.tar";
my $sourcedir2 = "$homedir/host_client/sabkuch.pl";
my $remote_path = "/local/home/hanmaghu";

# Main subroutines
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new ( $hostmachine, user =>$username, password => $password);
$ssh->scp_put($sourcedir,$sourcedir2,$remote_path)
     or die "scp failed \n" . $ssh->error;
# test() is similar to system() in perl openssh package
my $rc = $ssh->test('perl sabkuch.pl'); 
# check if test function returned or not -> this is never executed
if ($rc == 1) {
    print "test was ok , server established \n";
}
else {
    print "return from test = $rc \n";
}
exit;
```

The other script which invokes our server script is :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;              
system('tar -xvf test.tar');
exec('cd utpsm_run_automation && perl utpsm_lts_server.pl');
#system('perl utpsm_lts_server.pl'); 
# Tried with system but in both cases it doesn't return, 
# this xxx_server.pl is my server script
exit;
```

The server script is :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::INET;

#flush after every write
$| =1;

my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
    LocalHost => '0.0.0.0',
    LocalPort => '7783', 
    Proto => 'tcp',
    Listen => 5,
    Reuse => 1
);
die "cannot create socket $! \n" unless $socket;
print "server waiting for client on port $socket->LocalPort \n";

while (1)
{
    # waiting for new client connection
    my $client_socket = $socket->accept();

    # get info about new connected client
    my $client_address = $client_socket->peerhost();
    my $client_port = $client_socket->peerport();
    print "connection from $client_address:$client_port \n";

    # read upto 1024 characters from connected client
    my $data = "";
    $client_socket->recv($data,1024);
    print "rceeived data = $data";

    # write response data to the connected client
    $data = "ok";
    $client_socket->send($data);

    # notify client response is sent
    shutdown($client_socket,1);
}
$socket->close();
```

Please help how to execute this : in terms of design this is what i want but having this issue while implementation, can i do it some other work around method.

Answer (score 4):

In short, your 'driver' `sabkuch.pl` starts the server using `exec` -- which  never returns.  From [exec](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html)

> The "exec" function executes a system command and **never returns**; ...

(Emphasis from the quoted documentation.)  Once an `exec` is used, the program running in the process is *replaced* by the other program, see [`exec wiki`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_%28system_call%29). If that server keeps running the `exit` you have there is never reached, that is unless there are errors.  See Perl's `exec` linked above.

So your `$ssh->test()` will block forever (well, until the server does exit somehow). You need a *non-blocking* way to start the server.  Here are some options

- Run the driver in the background

  ```
    my $rc = $ssh->test('perl sabkuch.pl &');
  ```

  This starts a separate subshell and spawns `sabkuch.pl` in it, then returns control and `test` can complete. The `sabkuch.pl` runs `exec` and thus turns into the other program (the server), to run indefinitely. See [Background processes in perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Background-Processes). Also see [it in perlfaq8](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-start-a-process-in-the-background), and the many good links there. Note that there is no need for `perl ...` if `sabkuch.pl` can be made executable.
- See whether `Net::OpenSSH` has a method to execute commands so that it doesn't block.
- One way to 'fire-and-forget' is to [fork](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html) and then [exec](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html) in the child, while the parent can then do what it wants (exit in this case). Then there is more to consider. Plenty of (compulsory) information is found in [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html), while examples abound elsewhere as well (search for *fork and exec*). This should not be taken lightly as errors can lead to bizarre behavior and untold consequences. Here is a trivial example.

  ```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;               
    system('tar -xvf test.tar') == 0  or die "Error with system(...): $!";

    my $pid = fork;
    die "Can't fork: $!" if not defined $pid;
    # Two processes running now. For child $pid is 0, for parent large integer

    if ($pid == 0) {  # child, parent won't get into this block
        exec('cd utpsm_run_automation && perl utpsm_lts_server.pl');
        die "exec should've not returned: $!";
    }   
    # Can only be parent here since child exec-ed and can't get here. Otherwise,
    # put parent-only code in else { } and wait for child or handle $SIG{CHLD}
    # Now parent can do what it needs to...
    exit;  # in your case
  ```

  Normally a concern when forking is to [wait](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wait.html) for children. If we'd rather not, this can be solved by *double-forking* or by handling SIGCHLD (see [waitpid](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/waitpid.html) as well), for example. Please study `perlfaq8` linked above, [Signals in perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Signals), docs for all calls used, and everything else you can lay your hands on. In this case the parent should by all means exit first and the child process is then re-parented by `init` and all is well.  The `exec`-ed process gets the same `$pid` but since `cd` will trigger the shell (`sh -c cd`) the server will eventually run with a different PID.

  With `system('command &')` we need not worry about waiting for a child.

---

This is related only to your direct question, not the rest of the shown code.

Comment: Could you tell me how to fork and exit in perl : just like u said fire and forget types. could you share the code snippet for the same in perl

Comment: @hanish  Well, yes, sure.  However, that is a little different territory and I would have to request that you read up on that, too. It can get messed up if things go wrong.  There may well be another, simpler option -- I need to look at your code again and will let you know.

Comment: @hanish  I've added a breakdown of (some) options to the post.  In particular, the easiest and simplest is if you can just start the driver (that starts the server) in the background.  Please let me know how it goes.  Learning `fork` + `exec`is nice but it may distract you from the job on hand.

Comment: yes its working now , thanks , i never knew about background processes in perl ( i knew of nohup) , its working now. :) nevertheless below i put a fork-exec case , please let me know where i go wrong with that.

Comment: @hanish  I added a `fork`+`exec` example, suited to your case, to my answer. If you want to use it _please first play a lot with it in a safe manner, to catch all those errors and weird behaviors without doing damage to your system (or others)_.  For the purpose at hand I recommend to use `test('cmd &')`, since you say it's working.  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @hanish  Please provide feedback on this extensive answer.  Did it solve your problem? How did the fork+exec work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Well i figured the best way would be to fork out a child process and parents exists thus child can now go on forever running the server.pl

but it still is not working please let me knoe where in this code i am going wrong

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

system('tar -xvf test.tar');

my $child_pid = fork;

if (!defined $child_pid){
      print "couldn't fork \n";}

else {
        print "in child , now executing \n";
exec('cd utpsm_run_automation && perl utpsm_lts_server.pl')
        or die "can't run server.pl in sabkuch child \n";
}
```

the output is my script still hangs and the print statement "in child now executing " gets run twice , i dont understand why, 
i work mostly on assembly language hence this all is new to me.
help will be appreciated.

Comment: Like I say, there is a little more to it. Your first test checks whether the `fork` failed, that's it.  There is no separation of child and parent so they _both_ run through `else` and they _both_ start the server -- and there is no one to return. Worse, you can accumulate processes (or zombies) if this goes wrong.. I'd suggest you read a bit on it -- search SO and use links in my answer, and if there are problems post a question. I can add it to my answer as well, but that steers away from your purpose, which is better served by using simple `&` behind the command.

Comment: _I'd like to warn against playing with `fork` in production._  For example, in this code you started _two server processes_ to run in parallel. What if they, say, write files and stomp on each other in doing so, resulting in corrupt files? Or acquire some resource out of order? It can mess up your filesystem, or worse. By all means, play with it, but in small ways -- write separate programs. I can include it in my answer if you insist, but I am concerned about the health of your system. Please don't do it where it matters until you know it. Well, like any other code, just a bit more so.

Comment: @zdim, yes i think forking i would avoid it coz of possible danger you pointed, nevertheless if i had to have a code i want to know where its going wrong? could you please write a snippet for the same

Comment: Alright, I'll add it to my post. (I will _have to_ do that some other day, it is very late here now.)  I will let you know when I get to it.